# Wicket component won't refresh via AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a Wicket page with some components that should be updated via AJAX. I have the following AjaxBehavior:

```
private class MyAjaxBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

        @Override
        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
            super.renderHead(response);
            response.renderOnLoadJavascript("wicketAjaxPost(\"" + getCallbackUrl() + "\")");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigure(Component component) {
            firstComponent.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            secondComponent.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            firstComponent.replaceWith(createFirstComponent());
            target.addComponent(firstComponent);

            secondComponent.replaceWith(createSecondComponent());
            target.addComponent(secondComponent);
        }
    }
```

And I have a component hierarchy like this:

```
Page
- fragment1
  - fragment1-1
    - firstComponent
- secondComponent
```

The problem is `firstComponent` never refreshed after AJAX callback. `secondComponent` is updated correctly. I tried to move `firstComponent` to `frament1-1` (just  experiment) and it worked! I tried to use some extra fragments to wrap `firstComponent` but it didn't help.

I tried to debug Wicket's `AjaxRequestTarget.respondComponent()`. There is the following code:

```
        // Initialize temporary variables
        final Page page = component.findParent(Page.class);
        if (page == null)
        {
            // dont throw an exception but just ignore this component, somehow
            // it got
            // removed from the page.
            // throw new IllegalStateException(
            // "Ajax request attempted on a component that is not associated
            // with a Page");
            LOG.debug("component: " + component + " with markupid: " + markupId +
                " not rendered because it was already removed from page");
            return;
        }
```

`page` is null here for both `firstComponent` and `secondComponent` but the second one somehow gets re-rendered.

Any ideas why `firstComponent` is not re-rendered? Where should I dig? I use Wicket 1.4.22.

**UPD**

I tried to add the new component to `target` and not the old one. It creates the new component on the page but doesn't refresh the old one. So I have two components on the page instead of one. Also it breaks HTML markup structure for some reason. Like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="generated">new component is added here</div>
    <table>
        ...
        <tr>old component</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My wicket markup for `firstComponent` looks like this:

```
<div>
    <table class="summary" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <div wicket:id="firstComponent" />
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

...

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="firstComponentFragment">
    <th>title</th>
    <td><span wicket:id="someText"></span></td>
</wicket:fragment>
```

So you can see the new component is added outside the table.

Comment: You should use AjaxEventBehavior("domready"), this will fire you're event automatically when the dom is ready.

Comment: So finally I solved this via Javascript. :(

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to add a parent component (e.g. the Form itself) to the ajax response target so you are sure everything beneath it is updated. Thus no duplicates or missing updates. Updating just a special component is only required if you need the performance in that case. Even though you could define a wrapper container that you update just to make sure old markup gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update the newly created component:

```
@Override
protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Component old = firstComponent;
    firstComponent = createFirstComponent();
    old.replaceWith(firstComponent);
    target.addComponent(firstComponent);
}
```

Update: You cannot have a `<div>` inside a `<table>` tag, or the browser will append the update markup outside of the table.

Comment: So the only difference from my code it that the new component is added to `target` (not the old one). I tried to do it this way but it just adds the new component at the page and not refreshing the old one. And also it adds the new component in the wrong place in my HTML markup. I updated the answer, please take a look. Btw, with my `secondComponent` I add the old component to `target` and it refreshes correctly.

Comment: I believe you updated an answer. Well I don't actually use `div` inside `table`, it's just the way to define wicket fragment. It should be rendered into `<tr>...</tr>` and it is when I use `createFirstComponent()` for the first time I add this component to page (when the page is being loaded). Seems like it's some kind of Wicket bug.

Comment: It seems you use Wicket 1.4.x. The officially supported versions are 6.x and 7.x. The bug could have been fixed in the meantime. You are advised to upgrade!

Comment: @martin-g unfortunately I have to use the old version. Anyway I already implemented my feature using Javascript (and JQuery) just via `$('#firstComponent').replaceWith('...')`. It's awkward but it works.